# What happens if we don't software testing

Tags: testing, computer-science

It is really simple question.

However, really wondering.

I think even we don't software testing,

Program will work.

So, What happens if we don't software testing?

Comment: What happens? Simple, when the software stops working (and it will) you won't know it until some end-user complains.

Answer (score 2):

When you are so sure about the your software, why not just wait and see what happens? The simple fact you are asking the question means that you suspect you overlook something, and yes, you are. Testing software is not only about working or not, but concerns the quality of the software, including usability, performance, security, compatibility and so on and what can be improved. Are you sure color-blind people can use your software and your application is free from security vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 2):

The software might work, but you won't *know*<sup>1</sup> it works.

However, history has shown that all software has bugs. Your software *will* be tested. The question is, do you want your customers to find the bugs, or do you want to find them before the customers do?

<sup>1</sup> of course, even with testing you won't know with 100% certainty, but you will certainly know with more than 0% certainty. If you are writing a tic-tac-toe game, a low level of certainty is quite acceptable. If you are writing software for medical equipment, nuclear reactors, or airplanes, your level of certainty needs to be much higher.